# React Native :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build my react native app using `gradlew bundleRelease`
But I get

> Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
>   Keystore file not set for signing config release

I've generated `my-upload-key.keystore` file, and edited ./android/gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

And edited ./android/app/build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

But it isn't working. I'm using react-native 0.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project variable refer to `'MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE'` but your gradle properties are named similar to `MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE`. Make sure the names match (`UPLOAD` vs `RELEASE`)

Comment: Thank You, I didn't notice it.